# Array input to function

Tags: swift, function, swift2

I want to work with the numbers from the array `numbers` in the function. I just want multiply 2 with 3, 3 with 3, 5 with 3 and 2 with 3. However, I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
import Foundation

let numbers = [2, 3, 5, 2];

func num(number: [Int]...) {
    for item in number {
        let result = item * 3
        print (result)
    }

}

num(numbers)
```

> Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type '[Int]' and 'Int'

Comment: The problem is that `number: [Int]...` does not mean what you think it does.

Comment: remove in your `func num(number: [Int]...)` it `...`

Comment: you said you wanted to multiply 2 with 3, 3 with 3, 5 with 3 and 2 with 3. check out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an array of arrays to the function. The function parameter to `num()` should just be `[Int]` or `Int...`

### EDIT

Difference between `Int...` and `[Int]`

with `Int...` you can pass a variable amount of params without explicitly using an array:

```
func num(mult: Int, arr: Int...){

    for n in arr{
        println("num = \(n * 3)")
    }

}

num(1,2,3,4) // first param (1) == mult(iplier), rest are ints captured by arr
```

while with an array (`[Int]`), you have to explicitly pass an array:

```
func num(mult: Int, arr: [Int]){

    for n in arr{
        println("num = \(n * 3)")
    }

}

num(1, [2,3,4]) // 1 == mult(iplier,), rest are the Ints to operate with
```

Second solution is clearly cleaner.

I have never personally used `Int...`, but it definitely has its place... 
<strike>Needless to say that those `Int...` params need to go at the end of the parameter list...</strike>  (see @Qbyte's comment below on why this statement is wrong)

Comment: What is the difference between `[Int]` and `Int...`?

Comment: As of Xcode 7 beta 6 variadic parameters (i.e. `Int...`) can now appear anywhere in the parameter list not only at the end.

Comment: @Qbyte The statement about it coming at the end always was just an assumption because how would the compiler be able to distuingish between the params ? Sure, I can imagine how it would work with non-default parameters, but what if you had default parameters following the variadic parameter of the same type ? Or is that something you would have to take into account yourself, in which case my statement would still be kind of valid wrt correctness?

Comment: @Qbyte Sorry, I shouldn't answer things off the top of my head. I guess you'd have to specify the param "key" after the variadic param anyway, in which case your statement is correct...

Comment: @the_critic This should be a citation of those release notes: http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7_beta_6/Xcode_7_beta_6_Release_Notes.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Either delete the `...` to be able to pass an array :

```
let numbers = [2, 3, 5, 2]

func num(number: [Int]) {
    for item in number {
        let result = item * 3
        print(result)
    }

}

num(numbers)
```

or you can pass the values directly with a vararg:

```
func num(number: Int...) {
    for item in number {
        let result = item * 3
        print(result)
    }

}

num(2, 3, 5, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an array of arrays of `Int` (`Array<Array<Int>>`).

`Array<Int>`, which is `[Int]`, which is `Int...`, but `Int...` parameter value can't be an array of [Int], it should be sequence of `Int`s.
E.g.

```
func foo(bar: Int...) {
    // bar is [Int]
}

foo(0, 3, 13, 6) // parameter is sequence of `Int`s
```

Also, you could use `.map()` to apply transform to each element of array. And, using `Int` type as parameter is not efficient way of writing Swift code (you an not pass `Array<UInt>` as input parameter, etc.), protocol `IntegerArithmeticType` provides functions for `*` operator. All default Swift integer types conform to this protocol. So, the only way here is to use generic function with type `T`, where `T: IntegerArithmeticType`. Here is the final code:

```
let numbers = [2, 3, 5, 2]

/// Multilplies each element of array of `IntegerArithmeticTypes` by `multiplier`.
///
/// - Parameter multiplier: `IntegerArithmeticTypes` multiplier for each element of array.
/// - Parameter vals:        Array of `IntegerArithmeticTypes` in which each element 
///                          will be multiplied by `multiplier`
///
/// - Returns: Array with multiplied values from `values`
public func multipliedMap<T: IntegerArithmeticType>(multiplier: T, _ vals [T]) -> Array<T> {
    return vals.map  { $0 &* multiplier }
}

dump(multipliedMap(3, numbers)) 
// prints:
//
// ▿ 4 elements
// - [0]: 6
// - [1]: 9
// - [2]: 15
// - [3]: 6
```

PS: I used `&*` operator, because `IntegerArithmeticType` value may potentially overflow.

Comment: Since I'm a beginner to Swift and programming in general, I prefer the first answer of @Kametrixom because it seems to be way easier and less complicated. But thanks for your input. If I get better it may seem easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 var numbers = [2, 3, 5, 2];

func num(number: [Int]) 
{
   var result = 0
    for var j  = 0; j < number.count - 1  ; j++
    {
        result = number[j] * number[j + 1]
        print ("\(result)")
     }
}

print(num(numbers))
```

Comment: It's a bit overkill, don't you think? But thanks for that input.

Comment: but you said you wanted to multiply each index by each other

Comment: Well, first of all it gives me more than 4 solutions and second, some of them are even wrong. But again, thanks for trying to help. :-) Your answer is interesting and I'll look into it more tomorrow. :-)

Comment: Naah, I should get 4. 2*3=6, 3*3=9, 3*5=15 and again 2*3=6.

Comment: Just change the code you should get 3 answers 2 *3 and 3*5 and 5*2 , that's how it should work